# Fill in Cup from Coke Machine (Algorithm)

Tags: algorithm

Here is an interview question, will somebody give me some hint? I am thinking about DFS or BFS, however, I cannot think out a clear solution from my head.

> Three coke machines. Each one has two values min & max, which means if
>   you get coke from this machine it will load you a random volume in the
>   range [min, max]. Given a cup size n and minimum soda volume m, show
>   if it's  possible to make it from these machines.

Comment: If it's a Google interview question then you can just keep filling the cup until it overflows.

Comment: Paul, can you elaborate more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is assuming you're not allowed to overflow the cup. If you can overflow it, you can always make it.

Let's mark the machines with (min1,max1),(min2,max2),(min3,max3). a1,a2 and a3 shows the amount of times you've used each machine.

We need to find a1, a2 and a3 in order to satisfy :

```
Condition 1 : a1*min1 + a2*min2 + a3*min3 >= m
Condition 2 : a1*max1 + a2*max2 + a3*max3 <= n
```

Apparently it's not required to find the most optimal way to fill the cup (minimizing a1+a2+a3) so you can simply use DFS.

You use Condition 2 as the depth limit (meaning if Condition 2 isn't fulfilled you stop going deeper in the graph) and if you ever reach Condition 1 you have yourself the answer (return yes). If you finish the search and find no answers, return no.

Seeing as this is an interview question though, I really doubt that DFS or BFS would be the way to solve it. This could easily time out with big m and n values.